# hp dl140 g3 how to repair after failed bios update

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, bios

During updating bios to the new version (1.18) i got an error that computer can't read rom file. Then after reboot server did not start. Actually it starts but does not show anything, screen is blank, no system beeps or led signals.

The question is, how can i recover it? I can't find any information about.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a EEPROM programmer to reflash the BIOS chip with the correctly firmware to put this machine back in production.

If it's on warranty, I would recommend you to call to HP and explain the whole situation and find a solution for this problem with the vendor.

I do not recommend BIOS reflashing with a external programmer if you never done this. It's not really simple and you need some pieces of hardware that you probably don't have.